# Spin Control GetPos() value is delayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, controls

I have an edit control buddied with a spin control with the initial position set to 0. When the up arrow is clicked the edit box goes from 0 to 1, which is fine. But when I use `GetPos()` the `MyValue` is 0. When the spin control is incremented again from 1 to 2, the MyValue becomes 1.  When down arrow is pressed the edit box goes from 2 to 1, but the value becomes 2. It seems that the `MyValue` is always one action behind the spin control.

```
 BOOL CAlphaDlg::OnInitDialog() 
 {
           // default code left out to keep it short ...
           // TODO: Add extra initialization here
           // set range and initial position
           mSpinControl.SetRange(0, 3600); // range
           mSpinControl.SetPos(0); // inital position
           MyValue =  mSpinControl.GetPos();
           // display initial value in buddy editcontrol
           mEditControlDisplay.Format("%d", MyValue);
           UpdateData(false);
           return TRUE;
 }


 void CAlphaDlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
 {
        LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        UpdateData(true);
        int MyValue= mSpinControl.GetPos();
        std::cout << MyValue << std::endl;
        *pResult = 0;
   

 }
```

I have tried getting the value from the editcontrol but the value is exhibiting the same behavior. How do I get the value of the GetPos() to match what is showing in the edit control?

Thank you in advance.

*edit*: Here is the full code

```
// AlphaDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Alpha.h"
#include "AlphaDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CAlphaDlg dialog



CAlphaDlg::CAlphaDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_ALPHA_DIALOG, pParent)
    , mEditControlDisplay(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CAlphaDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, mEditControlDisplay);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SPIN1, mSpinControl);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAlphaDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_NOTIFY(UDN_DELTAPOS, IDC_SPIN1, &CAlphaDlg::OnDeltaposSpin1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CAlphaDlg message handlers

BOOL CAlphaDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    mSpinControl.SetRange(0, 10);
    mSpinControl.SetPos(0);
    int MyValue = mSpinControl.GetPos();
    mEditControlDisplay.Format("%d", MyValue);
    UpdateData(false);
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CAlphaDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CAlphaDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CAlphaDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CAlphaDlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
    UpdateData(true);
    int MyValue = mSpinControl.GetPos();
    std::cout << mEditControlDisplay << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyValue << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear, why you are calling [UpdateData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#updatedata) and then continue to manually populate controls, or manually read them back. That's what `UpdateData` should have done for you already.

Comment: @IInspectable My mistake, the UpdateDate(true) in the OnDeltaposSpin1 was used to retrieve data from the edit control when I tried to get the value of from it since it shows the correct value. It did not work and had the same delayed behavior.  I had removed the line of std::cout << mEditControlDisplay; and did not remove the UpdateDate.

Comment: What about the `UpdateData` call in `OnInitDialog`, though? That one is not needed, unless you aren't calling the base class implementation. Which you should call.

Comment: @IInspectable The UpdateData called in OnInitDialog is used to display the initial value of 0 in the edit control box.  Without it, the edit control box remains blank until the spin control is clicked.

Comment: That means, you aren't calling the base class implementation. Not calling the base class implementation prevents the dialog from properly initializing. That's why you want to provide *full* code.

Comment: @IInspectable If you think it would be helpful.  I have posted the full code, but it's all default stuff generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/107t5e65.aspx) (Remarks) says: When it processes the value returned, the control updates its current position based on the caption of the buddy window. Looks like the `UDN_DELTAPOS` msg is sent/processed before the buddy ctrl is updated. Try processing the `EN_CHANGE` msg (of the edit ctrl) instead, or else post a custom message and process that one. The `UpdateData(TRUE)` call updates the dialog variables (control contents->variables) but you make no use of these in this part of your code, so it's probably not needed.

Comment: You can also try the `EN_UPADATE` notification, if the `EN_CHANGE` one doesn't work (eg if it sent only if the edit ctrl is changed by the user). Otherwise try posting the custom message I mentioned above (in `OnDeltaposSpin1()`), and process this one. It will hopefully be placed at the end of the msg queue, and processed after the buddy edit ctrl is updated.

Comment: I am confused. If you have set the autobuddy setting then it will update the edit box for you with no code on your part.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, the autobuddy setting does update the edit box.  The problem is when I get the value from the editbox or from GetPos() it is always one action behind.

Comment: But why do you need to? If the edit control is auto updated then just access that value and ignore the spin control itself.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I tried your suggestion of en_update and en_change on the edit control, unfortunately neither worked.  The value is still one value behind what is being displayed on the edit control.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The edit control value is also one action behind what is being displayed in the editcontrol box.  So if I clicked the spin control to 10 the edit control box shows 10, but the mEditControlDisplay return 9.

Comment: Then have you considered using `GetWindowText` or `GetDialogItemText` to get directly from the control into a variable?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the help and suggestions.  It seems that the problems is that any eventhandler associated with the edit control or the spin control is signaled before the value change, @ConstantineGeorgiou Thank you for pointing that out. I just needed another member to grab the value after the event is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, consider mapping your edit box to a `int` and then you do not need to cast to a string. And the default value is 0 to begin with so the spinner will be OK. You can also switch off the auto buddy.

In the deltapos handler you could do this:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;

    SetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1, pNMUpDown->iPos);

    UpdateData(TRUE);

    CString a;
    a.Format(_T("%d"), iNumberValue);
    AfxMessageBox(a);
}
```

For me the results in the popup message and the edit control are the same.

## Update

You can workout what the new value would be by looking at the structure:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);

    int iCurrentPos = pNMUpDown->iPos;
    if (pNMUpDown->iDelta > 0)
        iCurrentPos++;
    else
        iCurrentPos--;

    CString strNewValue;
    strNewValue.Format(_T("%d"), iCurrentPos);
    AfxMessageBox(strNewValue);

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

## For Consideration

You might want to give some thought to [`CSpinButtonCtrl::SetAccel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cspinbuttonctrl-class#setaccel) which sets the acceleration for a spin button control.

In your case I don't think it is going to matter because your range is only 10
units. But if you had a larger range then it is possible that it would increment by more than one unit. It is just something to keep in mind.

According to this reference for [`UDN_DELTAPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/udn-deltapos) it says:

> The **iDelta** member of the structure is a signed integer that contains the proposed change in position.

So you could improve the code and increment/decrement based on the **`iDelta`** value instead of 1. This would factor in for acceleration. So:

```
int iCurrentPos = pNMUpDown->iPos + pNMUpDown->iDelta;
```

Comment: With this implementation, on the initial press of the spincontrol the AfxMessageBox(a) displays the int 0.  After I confirm "ok" the edit control then increments to 1.  Is there a way to have AfxMessageBox(a) to display the 1 on the initial press instead of 0?  Thanks

Comment: @TMa Just updated my answer with a little more information. Thanks for accepting it. Don't forget to upvote it too if you can. :)

Comment: Thank you. It's perfectly worked for my problem